# Opposite of joins/includes? in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I say something like `@business.branches.joins(:workers)` I can find all the branches that belong to @business that have workers.

**What if I want to find all the branches that belong to business that don't have workers?**

Comment: Workers belong to branches, branches belong to businesses

Comment: I deleted my answer because you give pieces of informations little by little. SO I suggest you read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no easy way to achieve this in rails.  The way I do this is to write a join in sql like the following

```
@business.branches
  .joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN workers ON (branches.id = workers.branch_id)')
  .where('workers.id IS NULL')
```

Comment: It's a shame Rails can't handle this. It seems it would be a common problem

Answer (score 0):

it is posssible through includes, because includes provides left-outer-join

```
@business.branches.includes(:workers).where("workers.branch_id": nil)
```